# How To append Element In Array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-2

I have one method in php that execute storedprocedure like this:

```
Function GetInTransitAndDelivery($Parameter)
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $query =  $this->db->query( " EXEC StoredProcedureName $Parameter");
        if (count($query->num_rows()) > 0)
        {
            $result = array();
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $result[] = array("EffectiveStatusId"=>$row->EffectiveStatusId,
            "EffectiveStatus"=>$row->EffectiveStatus,
            "RecordCount"=>$row->RecordCount);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

that give me result like this:

```
{

    "GetInTransitAndDeliveryResponse":[
        {
            "EffectiveStatusId":1,
            "EffectiveStatus":"abc",
            "RecordCount":7
        },
        {
            "EffectiveStatusId":6,
            "EffectiveStatus":"efg",
            "RecordCount":91
        }
    ]
```

But I whnt to result Like this :

```
{

    "GetInTransitAndDeliveryResponse":[
        {
            "EffectiveStatusId":1,
            "EffectiveStatus":"abc",
            "RecordCount":7
        },
         {
            "EffectiveStatusId":1,
            "EffectiveStatus":"efg",
            "RecordCount":7
        },
         {
            "EffectiveStatusId":1,
            "EffectiveStatus":"hij",
            "RecordCount":0
        },

        {
            "EffectiveStatusId":6,
            "EffectiveStatus":"klm",
            "RecordCount":0
        }
    ]
```

So how to append element in result array

thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you struggle? Is order important? How are the new elements constructed?

Comment: from where those extra 2 records came?

Comment: I want to push that hardcoded value in array

Answer (score 0):

Try array_push() function

[See Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer is modified based on your comment

```
<?php
//1 - I think your array element is as json string

$str = '{
    "GetInTransitAndDeliveryResponse":[
        {
            "EffectiveStatusId":1,
            "EffectiveStatus":"abc",
            "RecordCount":7
        },
        {
            "EffectiveStatusId":6,
            "EffectiveStatus":"efg",
            "RecordCount":91
        }
    ]
}';

//2 -  So make it first as associative array

$array = json_decode($str,true);

//3 - Then push array item

array_push($array["GetInTransitAndDeliveryResponse"],
    array(
        "EffectiveStatusId"=>1,
        "EffectiveStatus"=>"hij",
        "RecordCount"=>0
    ),

    array(
        "EffectiveStatusId"=>6,
        "EffectiveStatus"=>"klm",
        "RecordCount"=>0
    )
);

//4 - encode it as json string

$str = json_encode($json);

//5 - print it

echo $str;
```

Output:

```
{
    "GetInTransitAndDeliveryResponse":[
        {
            "EffectiveStatusId":1,
            "EffectiveStatus":"abc",
            "RecordCount":7
        },
        {
            "EffectiveStatusId":6,
            "EffectiveStatus":"efg",
            "RecordCount":91
        },
        {
            "EffectiveStatusId":1,
            "EffectiveStatus":"hij",
            "RecordCount":0
        },
        {
            "EffectiveStatusId":6,
            "EffectiveStatus":"klm",
            "RecordCount":0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i have tryed with array_push() but not getting proper result

Comment: what are you getting then?

Comment: It's return indexed elements

Answer (score 0):

use array_push();

my working example is below

```
    <?php
    $array = array("1", "2");
    array_push($array, "3", "4");
    print_r($array);
    ?>

// output will be
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

Comment: in this case append only one value but I want to add 3 value like "EffectiveStatusId":1,
            "EffectiveStatus":"abc",
            "RecordCount":7

Comment: you mean to say you are appending one more array in it ?

Comment: Right i want append array like element

Comment: then try array_merge(); it is used to merge two array

Comment: Thanks For replay @janak but I want to that element that stored prodedure return eg : Status:abc and Status:efc return from detabase then i want to skip that value form hardcode

Comment: if($row->EffectiveStatus != 'abc') then i want to push hadrcod value

Comment: ok try it
if()
{
 array_merge("array","array that you want to append (hardcoded)")
}
else

{
// do not merge array
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37853/discussion-between-imj4u-and-janak-prajapati)

Answer (score 0):

before transform array to json, add these elements like this:

```
$result[] = array(
    "EffectiveStatusId"=>1,
    "EffectiveStatus"=>"hij",
    "RecordCount"=>0
);

$result[] = array(
    "EffectiveStatusId"=>6s,
    "EffectiveStatus"=>"klm",
    "RecordCount"=>0
);
```

and you can append all elements you want.